# Reference Request: Discretization of Fourier decay of measures

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $\mu$ be a (complex) measure on the torus $[0,1]$. Then we can define its Fourier coefficients $\hat \mu(k)=\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i k x}dx$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$. We can also define its continuous Fourier transform $\hat \mu(\xi)=\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i \xi x}dx$ for $\xi\in \mathbb R$.

One theorem (A) states that $\mu (\xi)=O(|\xi|^{-\alpha})$ if and only if $\mu (k)=O(|k|^{-\alpha})$. It refers to Lemma 9.A.4 in Wolff's harmonic analysis notes (can be found on Page 63 of http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ilaba/wolff/notes_march2002.pdf), which is a slightly different version. So I would like to find a more direct reference for theorem (A).

Comment: It is because $\hat{\mu}(\xi) = \sum_k \hat{\mu}(k) \frac{\sin \pi (\xi-k)}{\pi(\xi-k)}$

Comment: @reuns How would you justify the convergence of the series on the right hand side? It may not be absolutely summable.

Comment: If $\hat{\mu}(k) = O(|k|^{-\alpha})$ then it is

Comment: You are right. I will try to prove the identity you wrote.